# IOS 7 screenshot tweak

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm trying to create a screenshot tweak for iOS 7 but all i am able to save is a blank image. 
This is my code:

```
UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenshotView.bounds.size);
        [[screenshotView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:fname atomically:YES];
```

Does anyone have a solution?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears you should not use `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` to render images (see [raywenderlich forum](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8993&start=10)) but `drawViewHierarchyInRect` instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

for compatibility reason i still haven't used `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` but the following code works. give it a try.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, myView.opaque, 2.0);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// do something with theImage
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set the output on a UIImageView**

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        imageSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    } else {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, window.center.x, window.center.y);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, window.transform);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x, -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageSize.width);
        } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.height, 0);
        } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.width, -imageSize.height);
        }
        if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
            [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        } else {
            [window.layer renderInContext:context];
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```